# What does $:: mean in puppet

Tags: configuration, puppet

I'm going through a module that manages network, in order to understand how puppet modules work, what I'm stuck on is understanding what $::nisdomainname is, where did it come from and what does "$::" mean and why is the nisdomain portion outside the define block? An excerpt from a file in the module is below, can someone help me with the understanding?

```
define network::global (
  $hostnamemod = '',
  $gateway = '',
  $vlan = '',
  $nozeroconf = '',
  $gatewaydev = ''
) {
  $nisdomain = $::nisdomainname ? {
    ''      => '',
    default => $::nisdomainname,
  }
```

Thanks in advance
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In puppet 3.0 and newer, scoping rules will change and you can no longer use `$variablename` to refer to a variable in global scope, the correct syntax is `$::variablename`. This syntax also works in 2.7, and maybe in older versions too.

Comment: ahh thanks, but then why wouldn't the other variables like "hostnamemod" also be set as $::hostnamemod = ''?

Comment: Because those are parameters to your define, not references to variables in global scope.

Comment: ok cleared it up now. Appreciate it.

Comment: One final point, if I may. does the nisdomainname check state, that if the nisdomainname is empty set it to empty otherwise default to setting it to the $::nisdomainname. Which if not defined would be empty, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, the check makes little sense to me actually.

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker It's not a requirement in 3.0 to specify top scope explicitly.  The changes in 3.0 affect dynamic scope only.